# Cannot resolve ASP.NET MVC error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm a new learner of ASP.NET MVC. This problem should be easy to answer for professions. I'm trying to submit a form (post comment), and getting error.

**Here is my controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(long id, CommentViewModel comment) {
    var service = new UserService();
    var articleService = new ArticleService();
    comment.UserId = service.GetUserByUsername(User.Identity.Name).UserId;
    comment.ArticleId = id;
    comment.CommentTime = DateTime.Now;
    articleService.AddArticleComment(comment);
    return View();
}
```

**here is my ViewModel**

```
public class CommentViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    public Int64 CommentId { get; set; }
    public Int64 UserId { get; set; }
    public Int64 ArticleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentTime { get; set; }
    public String CommentBody { get; set; }
}
```

**here is my View (HTML)**

```
<form class="form-stacked" id="comment-form" action="@Url.Action("Index", "Article")"   method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label class="control-label" for="commentTextArea">Leave a comment...</label>
    <textarea rows="3" id="commentTextArea" name="commentBody" class="span8"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" />
</form>
```

**this is URL**

```
http://localhost:58856/Article?Id=1
```

**and this is the Error Message**

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int64, TechCells.Services.ViewModels.CommentViewModel)' in 'TechCells.Web.UI.Controllers.ArticleController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

I guess MVC should automatically detect the `id` from the URL, and automatically assign ViewModel properties based on names. Right?

What is the reason for this error? How can I fix?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your route registration code look like?

Comment: @Jasen, It has only default route registration.  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "TcMainRoute",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index",
                });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Your form doesn't have an `<input name="id" />` (which is necessary per your action signature). Remember that MVC's action arguments are *incoming values*, so if this is a form submit, all those parameters need to be supplied (though sometimes they can be defaulted in a route definition, but I won't get in to that).</strike>

Mis-read and missed the Id coming from a GET parameter. Assuming you follow traditional form handling with a GET & POST action, you're passing the Id to the GET, it renders a view, then on POST the Id's dropped. So, two options:

- If you don't need it, remove the `long id` parameter or make it optional (`line id = 0`) so that MVC can carry on with a default value.
- If you do need it, make sure to pass it off in your `Url.Action()` as a routeValue so it's received back in.

---

Also, don't be afraid to use the HTML Helpers, like `Html.BeginForm`, `Html.LabelFor`, `Html.TextBoxFor`, etc.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Article",
  new { id = __ID_FROM_GET_REQUEST_ }, // to hand-off to POST action
  FormMethod.Post,
  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }
))
{
    @* I assume these are here to help reference what the comment is regarding *@
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ArticleId)

    @* are these ones auto-generated at creation time? if so, remove these. I
       don't know enough about your work-flow, so just going to place them for
       now. I also don't know what your validation requirements are. *@
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CommentId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CommentTime)

    @* Now we get in to user-interaction *@
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CommentBody)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.CommentBody, new { @class = "span8", rows = "3" })

    <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" />
}
```

Then for `LabelFor` to work, make sure you decorate your model:

```
/* ...snip ... **/

[Display(Name = "Leave a comment...")]
public String CommentBody { get; set; }

/* ...snip ... **/
```

Comment: You mean: long id = 0? And what about nullable?

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić: Either, though I suppose `long?` would be a better fit (given it flags an absent value more concisely).

Comment: i need id, to get the current article id from query string. but MVC automatically recognizes the id in the query string, right? look at the URL, there is id=1. why it is not getting the id automatically?

Comment: @TechCells.net: your'e not invoking Index action, try with http://localhost:58856/Article/Index?Id=1

Comment: @TechCells.net: Touche, missed that it's a GET parameter and not a POST. In that case it's probbaly because the URL you're generating to submit to is dropping the `id` (your `Url.Action()`).

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić: Assuming default routes, `Article` would be the controller, and `Index` the default action (`{controller}/{action}/{id}`)

Comment: @BradChristie: in that case, OP would need route param, not query string param - localhost:58856/Article/Index/1; but what about the rest of the model?

Answer (score 0):

Changing it to this

```
public ActionResult Index(long id = 0, CommentViewModel comment)
```

OR

this

```
public ActionResult Index(long? id, CommentViewModel comment)
```

will solve the problem.

The error is occuring because you are not passing any value for `id`. and `id` is not nullable. 
To solve this, either pass `id` or change the method signature as above.

Comment: id cannot be null, and cannot be 0. it should have some valid value.

Comment: In that case, You can either determine `id` in the code OR send `id` from the view using any input control like dropdown or hidden field.